# Shibboleth upgrade - deprecated features in v4.1.0

Tags: upgrade, saml, shibboleth, idp

I recently upgraded Shibboleth from v4.0.1 to v4.1.0. After the upgrade, I get the deprecated warning message regarding SAML2NameID. I am using this feature in "attribute-resolver.xml" conf file and couldn't find its replacement in the Shibboleth documentation. Can anyone suggest what should I use in place of SAML2NameID?

WARN [DEPRECATED:125] - [:] - xsi:type 'SAML2NameID', (file [conf/attribute-resolver.xml]): This will be removed in the next major version of this software; replacement is (none)

Comment: do you need that attribute? If not then you can remove it from attribute-resolver.xml.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using this feature in "attribute-resolver.xml" conf file and couldn't find its replacement in the Shibboleth documentation.

Using `SAML2NameID` encoders in the resolver is now deprecated, and you're given specific configuration to generate name ids for different saml protocols, SPs, per attributes, etc.

Per the docs,

> The saml-nameid.xml configuration file defines two list beans, each one an ordered list of "generator" plugins for the two different SAML versions. Each plugin is specific to an identifier Format, a SAML constant that identifies the kind of value being expressed. The generation process involves selecting a list of Formats to try and generate (see Format Selection below), and then trying each Format until an appropriate value is obtained by running each configured generator in order.

Please see [this link](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IDP4/pages/1265631671/NameIDGenerationConfiguration#Generators).